# Mediawiki: add script to page head in special namespace

Tags: mediawiki

Via this code I can add external script to page header on every page.

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] ='onBeforePageDisplay';

function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin )
{
  $script = '<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://relap.io/api/v6/head.js?token=<token>"></script>';
  $out->addHeadItem("Relap.io script", $script);

  return true;
};
```

How can I do same not in all namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the namespace via `$out->getTitle()->getNamespace()`.